# HashSet getting sorted

Tags: java, hashset

I am getting the unique elements from a arraylist into a hashset but it is being sorted by itself.But i need the data not to be in sorted order.How can it be done?

Comment: `HashSet` non guaranteed for order. But you can avoid duplicates. why cant you use same list.

Comment: HashSet order may change on next execution, you can use a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) to preserve order. For random order use a list and [shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29).

Comment: This problem has completely nothing to do with JSF/PrimeFaces. It has anything to do with basic Java. You'd have exactly the same problem when placing the code in a plain vanilla Java class with a `main()` method. I fixed the question tags.

Answer (score 5):

> *HashSet getting sorted*

The items of a [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) is not in a particular order at all, as explicitly stated in its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

Perhaps you meant to say that the items are "rearranged" in a different order than you have added the items and that this is undesireable.

In that case, just use [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) instead of `HashSet`. It maintains the elements in insertion order.

```
Set<T> unique = new LinkedHashSet<T>(arrayList);
```

Or, perhaps, if you prefer automatic ordering based on the element's `Comparable#compareTo()` implementation or would like to supply a custom `Comparator`, then use a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) instead.

```
Set<T> uniqueAndSorted = new TreeSet<T>(arrayList);
```

#### See also:

- [The Java Tutorials - Collecitons - Implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

What do yo mean by 'I want data not in sorted order'? Do you mean to say that you want the same order in which it is present in the list?
If so, you can create a LinkedHashSet and add the entries from the arraylist.

eg: 
       ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
       LinkedHashSet set = new LinkedHashSet();
       for (String temp : list) {
           set.add(temp);
    }

This will ensure the same order in which the elements are present in the arraylist.

Comment: Why are you repeating an already given answer? This is a Q&A site, not an old fashioned discussion forum or something :) If you agree an already given answer, then you don't need to repeat it, but just to upvote it (once you've earned sufficient reputation for it by posting good posts).